# Reduce the amount on the flutter counter, error: The operator '-' isn't defined for the type 'String'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile

I'm trying to reduce the amount on the counter for the shopping cart quantity, but I'm having this error, can anyone help me? thank you

[image: line 283]

[image: model]

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your `dataCart[index].price` type is `String`.
When you are using `dataCart[index].price *= _count[index]` it's actually return another String. Suppose your `dataCart[index].price` value is `"21"` and `_counter[index]` value is `3`. Then `dataCart[index].price *= _count[index]` will return `"212121"`. Thats why you are not getting any error for `dataCart[index].price *= _count[index]` this. But when you try to subtract an `Integer` from a `String` it will give you error.

So, you should change the type of `price` `String` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the type of `price` from `String` to `int`.
This is the solution to your error.